# Jittery motion when slowing time in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am using the code from this site to create slow motion effect

[Slow motion effect](http://www.41post.com/4258/programming/unity-slow-motion-and-rigidbody-behavior)

It works fine on the PC but it lags on the mobile phone.

Here is the code for android

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        { 
            Time.timeScale = 1.0f;  
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime * newTimeScale;  
            Time.maximumDeltaTime = Time.maximumDeltaTime * newTimeScale; 
        }
        else if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) 
        {
            Time.timeScale = newTimeScale;  
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime / newTimeScale;  
            Time.maximumDeltaTime = Time.maximumDeltaTime / newTimeScale;
        } 
    }
```

My guess is that the TouchPhase.Ended is begin called over and over again so I am getting this laggy effect since I tried doing the same on the PC with the KeyDown and KeyUp method and I got the same laggy effect but this should not be happening since touchCount is equal to 0. I dont know, I am allout of ideas. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the value of your `newTimeScale`?

Comment: The value of newTimeScale is 0.125. I have added a GUI button which you can press to slow and speed up the time and that works flawlessly but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TouchPhase you can make your own TouchUp and TouchDown

```
bool wasDown = false;

void Update()
{
  bool isDown = Input.touchCount > 0;

  if(!wasDown && isDown)
  {
    wasDown = true;
    //do touch down stuff, Time.timeScale = 1.0f etc
  }

  if(wasDown && !isDown)
  {
    wasDown = false;
    //do touch up stuff, Time.timeScale = newTimeScale etc
  }
}
```

Comment: This is how XNA handles key up and down and I was going to try this since I thought the code where the screen is not begin touched is running over and over again but  manage to fix the problem by doing this ----- if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {//Do the thing} and it works. Thanks for the reply.